# Unit test for controller doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created the following controller:

```
[HttpGet(“{provId}/m”)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetMForProv (int provId)
{
   var result = await _mediator.Send(new GetMForProvQuery() { ProvId = provId });

   if (result == null)
   {
      return NotFound();
   }

   return Ok(result);
}
```

And the following unit test:

```
public class GetMForProvTest
{
   private readonly ProvController _sut;
   private readonly Mock<IMediator> _mediator;
   private readonly Mock<IConfiguration> _configuration;

   public GetMForProvTest()
   {
      _mediator = new Mock<IMediator>();
      _configuration = new Mock<Iconfiguration>();

      _mediator.Setup(x => x.Send(It.IsAny<GetMForProvQuery>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
           .ReturnsAsync(new CatDto());

      _sut = new ProvController(_mediator.Object, _configuration.Object);
   }

   [Fact]
   public async Task ShouldReturnNotFoundResult_AfterGetMForProv()
   {
      var result = await _sut.GetMForProv(123); // this providerId does not exist

      Assert.Equal(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound, (result as NotFoundObjectResult).StatusCode);
   }
```

When I run the above test, on the line `Assert.Equal(…)` I get

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> (… as NotFoundObjectResult returned null.

How can I get this work?

Comment: Do you have a more complete stacktrace so we can see where the exception is thrown?

Comment: `ReturnsAsync(new CatDto());` is setup to return an object. So `if (result == null)` will be false and Ok will be returned. OkResult can not be converted to NotFoundResult that's why you are getting error. Change To `ReturnsAsync(null);` to solve the issue.

Comment: @Chetan `ReturnsAsync(null)` is not working. VS says that “The call is ambiguous between the following methods and properties: ‘ReturnsExtensions.ReturnsAsync<TMock, TResult> (IReturns<TMock, Task<TResult> >, TResult)’ and ‘ReturnsExtensions.ReturnsAsync<TMock, TResult>(IReturns<TMock, Task<TResult> >, Func<TResult>)’”

Comment: I think you need to cast to NotFoundResult instead of NotFoundObjectResult. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.notfound?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: I have tried and got the same Intellisense error “The call is ambiguous…” Also I’ve tried `ReturnsAsync((CatDto)null)` , `ReturnsAsync(default(CatDto))` and `ReturnsAsync(() => null)` but I got the “Object reference not set…”

Comment: @Chetan, you were right. You pointed to the right direction. I have solved this by using `NotFoundResult` and `.ReturnsAsync(() => null)`. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was supplied by Chetan in the comments:

> I think you need to cast to `NotFoundResult` instead of
> `NotFoundObjectResult`

You're not passing an object in `return NotFound()` so you should use `NotFoundResult` instead. The `As` operator is returning null which is why you're getting the exception. Update the Assert to:

```
Assert.Equal(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound, (result as NotFoundResult).StatusCode);
```

This was tested and is working for me using your original setup with this:

```
_mediator.Setup(x => x.Send(It.IsAny<GetMForProvQuery>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
         .ReturnsAsync(() => null);
```

---

**Original answer before you clarified you're using optional parameters**

Are you sure you're setting up the correct overload for `_mediator.Send`? It looks like you're setting up a different overload for `Send` in:

```
_mediator.Setup(x => x.Send(It.IsAny<GetMForProvQuery>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))...
```

which takes 2 parameters. However, you're calling it with a single argument in the controller:

```
var result = await _mediator.Send(new GetMForProvQuery() { ProvId = provId })
```

Could you try setting up the single argument overload and pass an action returning null:

```
_mediator.Setup(x => x.Send(It.IsAny<GetMForProvQuery>()))
           .ReturnsAsync(() => null);
```

Comment: Intellisense doesn’t let me use this one because it says “An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments”

Comment: Does it work with your original setup but using: `.ReturnsAsync(() => null)` @Homeboy53

Comment: Yes, look at my last comment from the original post. So, I get the “Object reference not set…”

Comment: It doesn’t work. Sorry for my confusing message.

Comment: @Homeboy53 I have tested this - Chetan's comment is correct - use `NotFoundResult` rather than `NotFoundObjectResult`. The cast is failing which is why you're getting the exception. Updated my answer

Comment: haldo, you’re right. I have changed to `NotFoundResult` and also used `ReturnsAsync(() => null)` and is working great. I saw your post after I’ve did some more testing and research and made it work eventually. Thank you for testing and pointing to the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix line:

```
.ReturnsAsync(new CatDto());
```

To

```
.ReturnsAsync((CatDto)null);
```

Because you return *CatDto* object and the result of casting *(result as NotFoundObjectResult)* is null

Comment: I have made the change but I get the same Object reference not set…